# How to count the number of the True in boolean matrix by use of Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

How to count the number of the True in boolean matrix by use of Tensorflow? Thanks!

```
[[False  True False False False  True False False False False]
[False  True False False False  True False False False False]
[False  True False False False  True False False False False]
[False  True False False False  True False False False False]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the boolean values to `tf.in32` and sum them

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = [
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False],
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False],
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False],
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False]
        ]


var = tf.Variable(data)
num_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(var, tf.int32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(num_true))
```

> 8

Comment: So cool, Thanks very much! In addition, how to index the tensor  through the boolean values?

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!
true_index = tf.cast(data, tf.float32)
num_true = tf.reduce_sum(true_index)
true_data = tf.mul(value_matrix, true_index)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
In [29]: data = [                                             
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False],
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False],
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False],
        [False, True, False,False,False, True, False,False,False,False]
        ]

In [30]: if_true = tf.where(tf.equal(tf.constant(data), True))
# or just if_true = tf.where(tf.constant(data))

In [31]: sess.run(if_true).shape[0] 
# only get the indices where the item is true, then the number of 
# returned indices amounts to the number of True
Out[31]: 8
```

This method is better in some way, for example to work out how many Falses are there and etc.

**Method 2:**

```
In [34]: if_true = tf.count_nonzero(tf.constant(data))                                              

In [35]: sess.run(if_true)
Out[35]: 8
```